# Setting Fbsdk frameworks for an iOS React-Native project

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, cocoapods, fbsdk

[Huge update]
Someone sent me this and it is much easier to read in order to install fbsdk with React Native: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/getting-started-ios
However, the problem was still the same:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'UIUserInterfaceIdiomTV'
```

I guess this is an error coming from the content pulled by CocoaPods, because **I was able to make the [sample example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/tree/master/Sample/HelloFacebook) work by simply deleting the same UIUserInterfaceIdiomTV** case (it used to be in a switch).

However, by following every step from the guide and eventually deleting the  UIUserInterfaceIdiomTV, I am faced with new compilation problems in my own project:
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAppEvents", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

If anyone can help...
Thanks for your help!

Comment: To be a little more clear, I've been trying different combinations of the steps from "Facebook SDK for iOS" knowing that I'm supposed to skip a few steps since Cocoapods is taking care of some, but I can't figure out what steps I'm supposed to do for the compilation to work.

Comment: I just answered a similar question, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904245/getting-reactnative-facebooksdk-working/36921878#36921878 I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, but I can't even get my project to compile. And I get the same error when I try to compile the [HelloFacebook sample](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/tree/master/Sample/HelloFacebook), by the way...

Comment: Hi @Crysfel, I've simply deleted the UIUserInterfaceIdiomTV case and got HelloFacebook to work.
However, new errors appeared in my app:  ```Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAppEvents", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTRootView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made the fbsdk to work (24/04/2016). To sum up the different steps in case you meet the same problem:

- If you meet the `The 'YourApp [Debug]' target overrides the 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' build setting...` warning after the command `pod install`, the `$(inherited)` is to be added in **the main project build settings** and not in the Pods
- UIUserInterfaceIdiomTV isn't recognized for now for an unknown reason, so in AppDelegate.m, if you get an error, just skim the case from the switch
- The info.plist must include a few lines that are not (yet) mentioned in the sdk installation guide. Here's the complete list of what you should add:

  `<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
      <dict>
          <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
          <array>
              <string>fb{your-app-id}</string>
          </array>
      </dict>
  </array>
  <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
  <array>
      <string>fbapi</string>
      <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
      <string>fbauth2</string>
      <string>fbshareextension</string>
  </array>
  <key>FacebookAppID</key>
  <string>{your-app-id}</string>
  <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
  <string>{your-app-name}</string>`

Do not forget to replace {your-app-id} by... your app id, and {your-app-name} by your app name.
Good luck to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This article answers your question directly...
https://colinramsay.co.uk/2016/04/29/go-serverless.html

I'll copy/paste the relevant details because I know a link isn't a decent answer on SOF.

Let’s install the [Facebook React Native SDK](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) via npm, that’ll give us a nice login button for free:

```
npm install --save react-native-fbsdkcore react-native-fbsdklogin
```

We need to install some native code to make this work, so let’s do that with CocoaPods. First we create a Podfile:

```
cd ios
pod init
```

Edit the file which was just created at FacebookAwsReactNative/ios/Podfile and add the following:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'React', :subspecs => ['Core', 'RCTImage', 'RCTNetwork', 'RCTText', 'RCTWebSocket'], :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
pod 'react-native-fbsdkcore', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdkcore'
pod 'react-native-fbsdklogin', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdklogin'
pod 'react-native-fbsdkshare', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdkshare'
```

You may need to perform some other steps here, as per the [Facebook documentation](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk#option-using-cocoapods). Go and have a read of that section just in case. Let’s install the pods and then we’ll have to faff around in Xcode for a bit.

```
pod install
open FacebookAwsReactNative.xcworkspace
```

Notice that we now use the xcworkspace file rather than the xcodeproj file; this is required for CocoaPods to do its thing.

Expand the FacebookAwsReactNative > Libraries folder and select all of the items in there and delete the references to them. This is because we’ve opted to use CocoaPods for React Native (see the `pod 'React'` line we added to the Podfile) so the items in Libraries are duplicates.